# How to manage and address supplementary data in R packages

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen2

I'd like to have supplementary data in my R package.
I know about `LazyData: true` in `DESCRIPTION`, but do not want to use it because the example data is quite large.
So I created a dir "*data*" which holds two `.RData` files and a `datalist`, which I added using `tools::add_datalist`.

```
datalist
supA.RData
supB.RData
```

Furthermore, I am using `roxygen2` to create a documentation - I want to document the `.RData` files, too. (I read somewhere, that this is even necessary.)

First question:

is it correct to document the two `.RData` files like:

```
#' Example data
#'
#' @format A data dable with 50000 rows and 670 variables:
"supA"
```

and add this to a `.R` file? (**never export**!!)

Second question:
At the moment i can not use `document()`, because the two variables are unknown/not in global environment. There has to be a clean way of doing this, right?

I hope to find help here,
Thank you!

**EDIT:**
For now, I removed the documentation for `supA` and `supB`. Loading data by call of the function `data("supA")` works alright for now

Comment: Have you tried asking on the r pkg devel mailing list? It's a mailing list of experienced package authors and they're fairly responsive and helpful

Comment: Yes, but since it is my first post I have to wait for moderator approval - I will keep this thread updated if I recieve an answer

Comment: Ah good, thanks! I do want to know the answer