# Retrieve path of supplementary data file of developed package

Tags: r

While developing a package I encountered the problem of supplementary data import - this has been 'kind of' solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696374/how-to-manage-and-address-supplementary-data-in-r-packages). 
Nevertheless, I need to make use of a function of another package, which `needs` a path to the used file. Sadly, using GlobalEnvironment variables here is not an option.
[By the way: the file needs to be `.txt`, while supplementary data should be `.RData`. The function is quite picky.]

So I need to know how to get the path supplementary data file of a package. Is this even possible to do?

I had the idea of reading the `.RData` into the global environment and then saving it into a `tmpfile` for further processing. I would really like to know a clean way - the supplementary data is ~100MB large...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `system.file()` to reliably find the path to the installed package and sub-directories, typically these are created in `your-pkg-source/inst/extdata/your-file.txt` and then referenced as

```
system.file(package="your-pkg", "extdata", "your-file.txt")
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you! I am just wondering: Is `path.package("your-pkg")` an option?

Comment: `path.package()` is also ok, but it returns the path to the installed package, and you're left adding the remaining parts of the path to your file; might as well let `system.file()` do that for you.